# How can I track version numbers with ASP.NET MVC and WinForms?

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, versioning

I'm having trouble finding what built-in mechanisms there are in the .NET framework for setting version information at build time.  Our development efforts are primarily directed at a WinForms application deployed with ClickOnce.  For this, we already have a system in-place and working.  I would like to try to extend what we already have to work with a few ASP.NET MVC projects.

Before our CI server starts building our WinForms application, we open up the .csproj file and tweak some values based on our CC.NET build number and the current SVN revision.  Major and minor version numbers are hand-set in a config file.

```
changeNodeValue('ApplicationVersion', version) // Version like "1.0.111.2222"
changeNodeValue('ApplicationRevision', revision) // SVN Revision like "2222"
```

So, we have something like this in a shared library.

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    return ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString();
else
    return "development";
```

This naturally works fine in our WinForms application.  Calling this method from an application not deployed by ClickOnce (our web projects) always returns "development".

Is there a way I can do the same sort of thing for our ASP.NET MVC applications, i.e., tweaking project files or build arguments to supply a version number to .NET?

Comment: As far as I know ApplicationDeployment is always related to click-once (or even similar deployment options). So if you didn't deploy your application with a suitable mechanism, you will end up in the else branch (because your application is not deployed at all).

You could rather try to get the version number, e.g. of the executing assembly. (by Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version)
On the other hand this requires the executing assembly to maintain the version number of the whole project, so it may not be appropriate.

Comment: @Andreas That is actually appropriate if I use `GetCallingAssembly()` instead, and along the lines of what I was thinking.  I'm failing to figure out how to set my assembly's version, however.

Comment: B: Is there a file called AssemblyInfo.cs in your project (probably under the Properties folder)? If so, you may modify the information that is given there. You could even automate this process. If not or for general introduction have a look at System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute to get a clue on how to generate Assembly Version Information yourself. Also watch out for related classes, but feel free to ask again :-)

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try to [MSBuildVersioning](https://versioning.codeplex.com/) DLL, it worked for me with ASP .NET MVC 2 and Winforms.